# Can matrix similarity be extended to include pseudoinverses instead of inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

We know two matrices $A \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n}$ are said to be similar, iff there exists a matrix $P$ such that $A= PB P^{-1}$.

Can this be extended to include pseudoinverses of rectangular matrices. Thus, given two square matrices of different sizes $C \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n}$ and $D \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times m}$, and a transformation matrix $Q \in \mathcal{R^{n \times m}}$, can $C=QD Q^+$ be defined as a legitimate similarity transformation?

Is there a name for this?

Comment: if $m \lt n$, which is a requirement if $Q^+Q = I_n$, then just use $E = \begin{bmatrix}
D & \mathbf 0 \\ 
\mathbf 0& \mathbf 0
\end{bmatrix}$  i.e. just zero pad it, and use a proper inverse so $C = VEV^T$, by completing Q into orthogonal matrix V.  (I assume pseudo inverse has that standard meaning e.g. in Ordinary Least Squares.)

Comment: @user8675309 Thats a pretty cool idea. And I think it would work if $m<n$ which basically adds some zeros to the eigenvalues of $C$.  But in my case, $m>n$, can something be done in this case?

Comment: @user8675309 I basically want a way to compute the inverse of $C$ and the eigenvalues of C in terms of those of $D$.  If you can think of something, this would be a big help

This is a related question I put up 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522695/can-diagonalization-of-a-positive-definite-matrix-be-used-to-compute-its-determi

Comment: re: your first comment, please tell me what $Q^+Q $ equals.  If it is the typical pseudo inverse that i'm aware of, it should be the identity matrix.  Maybe its a projector. Also what does $QQ^*$ equal? You need to explain what you are referring to (i.e. there is only one notion of actual inverse, but drazin, moore penrose and many notions of pseudo inverse exist, you may as well be specific). One way or another there's projections sitting around here.

Comment: The pseudo-inverse is the mooore-penrose one.  $QQ^+=I_{n \times n}$